# Makefile - how to differentiate between a variable assignment and a command

Tags: bash, makefile

I have the following code in my Makefile, but I get the error mentioning that `O?=2` is not a command that `sh -c` can run. What am I doing wrong here?

```
gcc:
    O?=2
    @if test -z "$(DEBUG)" ; then \
      g++ -O${O} *.c -o palindrome ; \
    fi
```

I am trying to set `O` to `2` if the user did not provide it, and then build my palindrome executable.

---

Exact error:

```
$ make gcc
O?=2
/bin/sh: O?=2: command not found
make: *** [gcc] Error 127
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it outside the command, so that it gets processed by "make" instead of the shell:

```
O?=2
gcc:
    @if test -z "$(DEBUG)" ; then \
      g++ -O${O} *.c -o palindrome ; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `O?=2` is not an assignment, but a command executed to rebuild target `gcc`. This means it is fed to $(SHELL), which doesn't know a thing about it. If you want a variable assingment, put it on line by itself and not as a part of commands:

```
O?=2

gcc:
    @if test -z "$(DEBUG)" ; then \
        g++ -O${O} *.c -o palindrome ; \
    fi
```

You can just use `O = 2`. When the user provides a value on the command line it will override it:

```
make O=1
```

will use `-O1` for optimization.